# breezejs entity query with select returning undefined

Tags: breeze

With the code below I am having an issue where not all the columns are return data in the data.results array.   For example if col4 is null in the database for row 1 then data.results[0] does not contain an element for col4,  but row 2 has a value then data.results[1] will contain the value for col4.   I would like each return item in the array to contain all items with the database value or null.  If null can't be returned then an empty string would do.

```
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
             .from('mytable')
             .where('col1', 'substringof', '2')
             .select('col1,col2,col3,col4')
             .orderBy('col1')
             .take(200);


    return _manager
        .executeQuery(query)
        .then(function (data) {
            return data.results;
        })
        .fail(queryFailed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default breeze does not serialize null values in its JSON results. This was a deliberate choice to reduce the breeze payload over the wire.  And..  this is not typically an issue with queries that return "entities". i.e. data for which breeze metadata exists. Because the properties are already defined on such entities.

But if you are returning an anonymous result as you are, then this can be a problem.  You can obviously work around it because you know the properties that you are requesting and can update them after the query if they are not in the result.

But you can also change breeze's default configuration to accommodate this via the "BreezeConfig" class.

BreezeConfig enables customization of components supporting Breeze-related operations in the Web API. BreezeConfig defines default behaviors; you can substitute your own behaviors by deriving from it and overriding its virtual methods. Breeze.NET will discover your subclass among the assemblies referenced by your project and use it instead of BreezeConfig.

To use BreezeConfig to configure the Json.Net serializer with specific settings. You can replace those settings by writing a subclass of BreezeConfig that overrides the 'CreateJsonSerializerSettings' method as shown in this example:

```
public class CustomBreezeConfig : Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig {    
  protected override JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings() {   
    var baseSettings = base.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();      
    baseSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
    return baseSettings;  
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, but please mark the item as answered so I don't have to keep going back to check on it. :) thx